# Integral involving square roots and Bessel functions

Tags: integration, summation, special-functions, bessel-functions

During my research I came upon the following definite integral involving Bessel functions, which I have no idea how to solve.

$\int_{-1}^{1}{dx I_{0}(a\cdot sin(bx) \cdot \sqrt{1-x^2}})$

Where $a$ is complex and $b$ is real.

The first observation is that the integral is even, therefore we can multiply by two while changing the limit to be between 0 to 1.

From here I used a series expansion for the Bessel function in which I also used the bionomial theorem, allowing me to use a known integral for
$\int{x^n\cdot sin^m(x) dx} $, this causes another series expansion which is combined with integral which is solvabale. The problem is ,I am left with hypergeometric function which I have been able to write explicitly summed with a term which holds 6 sums, which I don’t seem to be able to solve.

where in the image below you can see what I got. $a$ and $b$ are switched for $\xi$ and $\rho$.

[[image: where I got , <span class=]$a$ and $b$ are switched for $\xi$ and $\rho$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXHo9.jpg)

Comment: Maybe expand function with series at `x=0` and then integrate: $$I_0\left(a \sin (b x) \sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\approx 1+\frac{1}{4} a^2 b^2 x^2-\frac{1}{4} a^2 b^2 x^4-\frac{1}{12} a^2 b^4 x^4+\frac{1}{64} a^4 b^4 x^4 \text{+...+}$$. With 10 term 2 digits are corect.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the series expansion of the Bessel function

$$I_0\left(a \sin (b x) \sqrt{1-x^2} \right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ a^{2n}}{4^n \,(n!)^2 }\,\Big[\left(1-x^2\right) \sin ^2(b x)\Big]^n$$ and the problem reduces to the computation of
$$J_n=\int \Big[\left(1-x^2\right) \sin ^2(b x)\Big]^n\, dx$$ which does not make problem except finding its general formula
$$12b ^3\,J_1=8 b^3+6 b \cos (2 b)-3 \sin (2 b)$$
$$2560b^5\,J_2=1024 b^5+640 \left(4 b^2-3\right) \sin (2 b)+5 \left(3-16
   b^2\right) \sin (4 b)+$$ $$3840 b \cos (2 b)-60 b \cos (4 b)$$

I have the feeling that, whatever you could do with the integrand in $J_n$, you will face a lot of difficulties.

For example, suppose that $b$ is small
$$\left(1-x^2\right) \sin ^2(b x)=b^2 +\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{2^{2 k-3} b^{2 k-2} \left(4 b^2+2 k (2 k-1)\right)}{\Gamma   (2 k+1)}\, x^{2k}$$ but now we need to handle its $n^{\text{th}}$ power
and here will come some nasty hypergeomtric functions but, may be (?), it could be simpler than all the summations you have.

Comment: $$\int_{-1}^1 \left(\left(1-x^2\right) \sin ^2(b x)\right)^n \, dx=\frac{2}{1+2 n}+\sum _{j=1}^n \frac{(-1)^j 2^{1-2 n} b^{-\frac{1}{2}-n} j^{-\frac{1}{2}-n} \sqrt{\pi }
   J_{\frac{1}{2}+n}(2 j | b| ) \Gamma (1+n) \Gamma (1+2 n) \text{sgn}(b)^{\frac{1}{2}+n}}{\Gamma (1-j+n) \Gamma (1+j+n)}$$ or MMA code:`Integrate[((1 - x^2)* Sin[b x]^2)^n, {x, -1, 1}] == 
 2/(1 + 2 n) + 
  Sum[((-1)^j 2^(1 - 2 n) b^(-(1/2) - n) j^(-(1/2) - n) Sqrt[\[Pi]]
     BesselJ[1/2 + n, 2 j Abs[b]] Gamma[1 + n] Gamma[1 + 2 n] Sign[
     b]^(1/2 + n))/(Gamma[1 - j + n] Gamma[1 + j + n]), {j, 1, n}]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk. Thanks again fot your help !

Comment: Thank you both ! I currently don’t want to use an approximation for the solution , so I think @MariuszIwaniuk is a great answer because it seems “simple” enough to continue what I was doing